# Insert data into database faster

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to insert bulk data in 1000 tables. Data is already validated against constraints and indexes. I want to insert this data in minimal time frame. In that case is only disabling only fine or should I disable Indexes also (if required then how to disable the indexes.) in MS-SQL Server

Comment: There are many many guides online to do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SQL Server Integration Services` package for fast inserting large amounts of data.

There you can control the amount of rows being inserted as bulk data in a single transaction, number of threads and many other options. Also please check SSIS performance tuning [guide](http://henkvandervalk.com/speeding-up-ssis-bulk-inserts-into-sql-server). One of them, actually

Though I have never tried 1000 tables, I am sure SSIS will be great since insertion would be done in parallel and max degree of parallelism will be automatically managed by the server. Our production ETL package spends 25 minutes total to process (not only inserts) ~700 mln source1 data and ~20 mln source2 data.